# How to use OpenCV Color Conversion Codes to LBGR

Tags: opencv, color-space, color-conversion

I [came upon](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/e77a5d5f13c18449e38a570fb9d1309f82f95e35/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/types_c.h#L220) the *undocumented* OpenCV color conversion codes:

- `CV_Luv2LBGR`
- `CV_Lab2LBGR`
- `CV_Luv2LRGB`
- `CV_Lab2LRGB`

Apparently, they return the `L` channel in addition to the `BGR`/`RGB` channels.

However, I cannot seem to get them to work, I suspect the implementation code  ignores this and simply returns `BGR`.

How can I use them and why aren't they documented?

Comment: I'm curious as to why this would be of use to you? Of course, you can always just keep the L channel and convert. Which version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Well, mostly out of curiosity.